# Dml Exception Update failed

Tags: trigger

I want to update the priority of the case based on transaction item and case type. It works perfectly when I use after insert event but it has

> System.DmlException: Update failed

error when i use after update. please help. Thanks

```
for (Case case1 : Trigger.new){
        updatePriorityId.add(case1.Id);
    }
        for(Case case2 : [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Origin, Case_type__c,Transaction_Group__c, Transaction_Item__c,
                          Priority FROM Case WHERE Id =: updatePriorityId]){

            If(case2.Case_type__c != NULL && case2.Transaction_Item__c != NULL){
                if(case2.Case_type__c == 'Complaint'){

                case2.Priority = 'Critical';
                updatePriority.add(case2);
                }

                else if(case2.Case_type__c == 'Inquiry'){
                case2.Priority = 'Medium';
                updatePriority.add(case2);
                }
                else if(case2.Case_type__c == 'Request'){
                    if(case2.Transaction_Item__c == 'Reactivation'){

                    case2.Priority = 'Critical';
                    updatePriority.add(case2);
                    }

                    else{
                    for(String priorityHigh : forRequestTransItemsHigh){
                        if(case2.Transaction_Item__c == priorityHigh){

                            case2.Priority = 'High';
                            updatePriority.add(case2);
                        }   
                    }
                    for(String priorityMedium: forRequestTransItemsMedium){
                        if(case2.Transaction_Item__c == priorityMedium){

                            case2.Priority = 'Medium';
                            updatePriority.add(case2);
                        }
                    }
                    for(String priorityNormal : forRequestTransItemsNormal){
                        if(case2.Transaction_Item__c == priorityNormal){

                            case2.Priority = 'Normal';
                            updatePriority.add(case2);
                        }
                    }

                }
                }
                update updatePriority;
         }

    }
```

Comment: Can you share the full exception message?

Comment: you'll get more support from the community if you properly indent your code; also - all these nested ifs cry out for refactoring this method into something more understandable